# How to show master-detail data on an ASP.NET mvc page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parent-child, master-detail

I've already read several SO questions about this topic, but honestly most of them have been way too complex for me.  I'm very new to ASP.NET mvc.

I have a sample ASP.NET mvc 4 app that I created by following along with (and deviating just a bit from) the Movie database tutorial.  It has the built-in account bits, the Entity Framework (which has turned out to be a pain any time I change anything) plus 2 models that I built myself based on the models from the tutorial:

1) Bug

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MasterDetailPractice.Models
{
    public class Bug
    {
        public int BugID { get; set; }
        public string BugTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime BugDate { get; set; }
        public string BugStatus { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength]
        public string BugDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class BugDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Bug> Bugs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

}
```

2) Comment

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MasterDetailPractice.Models
{
    public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public int BugID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength]
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run my app I'm able to go to /Project and get the standard Index view with the Add link, where I can add a Bug.  Once added, I see the usual Edit/Details/Delete links.

When I run my app I'm also able to go to /Comment and get the standard Index view with the Add link, where I can add a Comment.  Once added, I see the usual Edit/Details/Delete links.

Up to this point, I'm OK.  The CRUD forms work, they just don't work *together*.

THE PROBLEM:

Currently, in order to make a Comment apply to a Bug, I have to actually input a BugID into the /Comment/Create form.  And then the Comments are all only available at the /Comment/ route.

Instead, I need the following to happen:

- The "Add Comment" form should automatically know what BugID to
  save without a user having to input it.
- A master-detail presentation of the data: The /Comment/Index view should appear at the bottom of the /Bug/Edit and/or Bug/Details page and show only the Comments related to the current Bug.
- The "Add Comment" link should only appear from the /Bug/Edit or
  /Bug/Details page, so Comments are never added without relating to a Bug.

It's kind of amazing that I haven't been able to figure this out myself, after spending 3 days poring over every Google result and SO post I can find on the topic.  That said, here I am, hoping to learn the simplest possible implementation of this.

Do I need to post more code (the Controllers, for example, or the Views) in order for this question to be properly answerable?

Looking forward to getting the slow-learning train to start pulling out of the station...

Answer (score 0):

Okay you need to do a few things.

First, create a new action method in your CommentController that looks like this.

```
public ActionResult Index(int bugId)
{
    // Your logic to fetch all comments by BugID through EntityFramework or whatever
    return View(data);
}
```

Now, in your Bug/Edit.cshtml or Bug/Details.cshtml pages add the following line to render those actions inline.

```
@Html.RenderAction("Index", "Comment", new { @bugId = Model.BugID }
```

In this case, you should be returning a BugModel back to your Bug/Edit.cshtml or Bug/Details.cshtml anyway as your model.

This should show you the form you need, with the BugID from the model being passed through.

For your last question, just put the "Add Comment" link within your Comment/Index.cshtml view since it will only appear anyway within the context of a bug. You will probably need to wrap this around a form that posts to your CommentController.

Here's a helpful link on working with forms in ASP.NET 4.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation